# $L_H(X)$ is real vector space,

Tags: functional-analysis

Please help demonstrate that applies: $L_H(X)$ is real vector space, where $X$ is Hilbert space (real or complex), and $L_H(X)$ the set of all hermitian operator on $L(X).$

Thanks for your help and your attention. Thanky very much

Comment: What's the problem? You just check the vector space axioms, which is pretty straightforward. Have you tried this?

Comment: Do you know what a vector space is?

Comment: I now what the vector space

Comment: I now what the vector space, but I didint know how to  prove this example, please if you can you please make this, please

Comment: If you're at the point in your career that you're studying functional analysis but cannot verify the vector space axioms, you should probably speak with your professor rather than us here. This site is to help with specific problems, but you seem to be struggling with some of the more basic concepts in linear algebra, which is a big, red flag when you're being asked questions about operators on a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A, B \in L_H(X)$, we have $A^\dagger = A$ and $B^\dagger = B$; then for $a, b \in \Bbb R$, we need to show that $aA + bB \in L_H(X)$; that is, that $(aA + bB)^\dagger = aA + bB$.  This is most directly done by falling back on the fundamental definitions:  we recall that a complex Hilbert space such as $X$ is equipped with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ which maps $X \times X \to \Bbb C$ and obeys, for all $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in X$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb C$:

$\langle x_1, y_1\rangle = \overline{\langle y_1, x_1 \rangle}, \tag{1}$

where $\bar z$ denotes the complex conjugate of any $z \in \Bbb C$;

$\langle x_1, y_1 + y_2 \rangle = \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle + \langle x_1, y_2 \rangle, \tag{2}$

$\langle x_1+ x_2, y_1\rangle = \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle + \langle x_2, y_1\rangle, \tag{3}$

$\langle x_1, \alpha y_1 \rangle = \alpha \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle, \tag{4}$

$\langle \alpha x_1,  y_1 \rangle = \bar \alpha \langle x_1, y_1 \rangle, \tag{5}$

$\langle x_1, x_1 \rangle \ge 0, \tag{6}$

$\langle x_1, x_1 \rangle = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_1 = 0. \tag{7}$

(1)-(7) define a norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ on $H$ *via* the equation

$\Vert x_1 \Vert^2 = \langle x_1, x_1 \rangle, \tag{8}$

where we take $\Vert x_1 \Vert \ge 0$ in (8); $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ defines the topology on $H$, and since $X$ is Hilbert, it is complete with respect to this norm (i.e., Cauchy sequences defined with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ converge to limits in $X$).  These are basic facts concerning the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $X$; I re-iterate them here for the sake of completeness; furthermore, denoting by $L(X)$ the set of *all* bounded operators on $X$, the Hermitian adjoint $C^\dagger$ of any $C \in L(X)$ is best defined *via* the inner product, though in the event that $\dim X < \infty$, so that elements of may be thought of as matrices of finite size, we can simply take $C^\dagger$ to be the conjugate transpose $\bar C^T$ of $C$ provided $C$ is expressed in terms of an orthonormal basis; but when $\dim X = \infty$, it is better to work directly from $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, thus:  $C^\dagger \in L(X)$ is defined to be the *unique* operator such that

$\langle C^\dagger x_1, y_1 \rangle = \langle x_1, Cy_1 \rangle \tag{9}$

for any all $x_1, y_1 \in X$.  (That $C^\dagger$ may be uniquely so defined is a standard fact whose validation I leave to my reader's research.)  It is easy to develop properties of $C^\dagger$ from (9) in a coordinate-independent, basis-free way, *viz.*, $C^{\dagger \dagger} = C$, since we have

$\langle x_1, Cy_1 \rangle = \langle C^\dagger x_1, y_1 \rangle = \overline{\langle y_1, C^\dagger x_1 \rangle} = \overline{\langle C^{\dagger \dagger} y_1, x_1 \rangle} = \langle x_1, C^{\dagger \dagger} y_1\rangle \tag{10}$

holding for all $x_1, y_1 \in X$.  (10) is indicative of the kind of argument we need to show that $aA + bB \in L_H(X)$; indeed we have

$\langle (aA + bB)^\dagger x_1, y_1 \rangle = \langle x_1, (aA + bB)y_1 \rangle = \langle x_1, aA y_1 \rangle + \langle x_1, bBy_1 \rangle$
$= a \langle x_1, Ay_1 \rangle + b\langle x_1, By_1 \rangle = a\langle A^\dagger x_1, y_1 \rangle + b\langle B^\dagger x_1, y_1 \rangle = \langle (aA^\dagger + bB^\dagger)x_1, y_1 \rangle, \tag{11}$

where we have used (9), (4), (5) and the fact that $a, b \in \Bbb R$, so that $a = \bar a$, $b = \bar b$, in (11).  Since (11) holds for all $y_1 \in X$, we must have

$(aA + bB)^\dagger x_1 = (aA^\dagger + bB^\dagger)x_1 \tag{12}$

for all $x_1 \in X$, whence

$(aA + bB)^\dagger = aA^\dagger + bB^\dagger = aA + bB, \tag{13}$

since $A^\dagger = A$ and $B^\dagger = B$; this proves the desired result, i.e., that $L_H(X)$ is a real linear subspace of $L(X)$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***